# When to create release branch in git flow?

Tags: git, git-flow

Our team is using git flow and we are doing continuous release about every two months. I'm a little confused about when we should create release branch.

For example in following case, there is a bug at last release and it should be fixed at this release, should i create release branch firstly and create bugfix branch from release branch or just create it from develop, do all feature development and merge back to develop, then create release branch from develop?

Should I push little bugs to release branch directly without creating bugfix branch?

Should I just merge one single commit from develop which comes from feature branch or bugfix branch to release branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually a release branch gets branched from develop branch. On the release branch the version gets incremented and then it get merged into master branch. After merging release branch into master branch and back into develop branch you should additionally create a Tag from the master branch and name it according the verison number of the previously released version.

> For example in following case, there is a bug at last release and it should be fixed at this release, should i create release branch firstly and create bugfix branch from release branch or just create it from develop, do all feature development and merge back to develop, then create release branch from develop?

In this case you would create a feature or bugfix branch for the bug, fix it and merge it into develop. Afterwards you will do all feature development and as soon as you are ready for release, create a release branch from develop branch and proceed as described above.

> Should I push little bugs to release branch directly without creating bugfix branch?

You should not develop on the release branch but on the develop branch. The release branch could be deleted after merging it into master and develop and then be created again when releasing next version.

> Should I just merge one single commit from develop which comes from feature branch or bugfix branch to release branch?

If you want to release a new version containing just 1 feature or 1 bugfix just create a new release branch from develop branch and proceed as described above for creating a release. There is no reason for not doing so (i.e. if you want to create a bugfix release containing just 1 bugfix)...

For more details about GitFlow see [here](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)

Comment: So confused about whether should directly develop release branch,  my manager told me it's fine, so did above answer. but you said no.@rufer7

Comment: @SummerX you should not develop directly on the release branch. There is no such statement in any of the answers. Even git cheatsheet points out, that release branch is just used for release commits and not for development purposes.

Comment: [Support preparation of a new production release
Allow for minor bug fixes and preparing meta-data for a release], which is said in https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/

Comment: @SummerX ok I see. Even then if possible I would try to avoid fixing bugs after creation of release branch as comprehensibility suffers

Comment: actually, I did it like you, always create bugfix and feature branch ,avoid fixing bugs in release branch, but my manager told me it's ok except complex feature.

Comment: I would not delete release branch for adding future bug fix for the release.

Answer (score 0):

So if you are doing continuous releases about every two months then I would suggest you to start your next release(1.0) development work into main Development branch.Once your development is done per the release(1.0) commitment then cut the release branch and have it deployed to you staging/pre-prod/QA environments. While your release(1.0) is being tested you can have your developers working on main development branch for next release(1.x or 2.x).So this will not stop your development. Now if QA finds a defect in you release(1.0) then have developer fixed it on main development branch and then you can cherry pick that particular fix and merge it with release(1.0) branch. Follow this approach for all defects QA finds during the testing. Once release(1.0) gets successfully tested and sign off, deploy it to PROD and merge it to master branch.

**Question 1: If there is a bug at last release and it should be fixed at this release, should i create release branch firstly and create bugfix branch from release branch or just create it from develop, do all feature development and merge back to develop, then create release branch from develop?**
Answer:If you find a PROD bug in release(1.0) while developer is still coding for release(1.x) then have it coded and fixed in 1.x as other feature ir user stories.How ever if you found a PROD bug in release(1.0) after release branch(1.x) has already been cut from the main development, then you have two options.
A) if its a urgent issue, then create a hotfix branch from master have it fixed and tested on non-prod environments and get it deployed to the PROD. Since its hotfix which is urgent all testing and other activities of regular release(1.x) need to be on hold while hotfix is getting tested.
B) if its not a hotfix then follow the same approach which I explain for defect above. Which mean assign it to a developer and have him fix the bug and checkin back to main development branch.Then cherry pick the change and merge it to release(1.x) branch and have it tested and then deploy it to PROD.

**QUESTIONS:Should I push little bugs to release branch directly without creating bugfix branch?**
Answer:You can skip bugfix branch, however it all depends on the timing. If issue is urgent then you have to create a bugfix/hotfix branch from master so that it can be tested and deployed quickly. Creating branch from master will assure that un-tested and non-hotfix related code wont gets deployed with hotfix.If issue is non urgent then you can have it go through the release branch itself.

**QUESTIONS:Should I just merge one single commit from develop which comes from feature branch or bugfix branch to release branch?**
Answer: Certainly, that is called "Cherry picking" and we all do it including google team.